# Trouble installing subkey

Tags: substrate

When I run `cargo build -p subkey --release` in `substrate-node-template`, I get `` error: package ID specification `subkey` did not match any packages Did you mean `subtle`? `` Please, how can I fix this

Answer (score 1):

There is a subcommand `node-template key` that exposes most of subkeys functionality.

To get subkey from substrate's main repo, see here: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/knowledgebase/integrate/subkey